# Writing unicode strings via sys.stdout in Python

Tags: python, unicode, macos, terminal, stdout

Assume for a moment that one cannot use `print` (and thus enjoy the benefit of automatic encoding detection). So that leaves us with `sys.stdout`. However, `sys.stdout` is so dumb as to [not do any sensible encoding](http://bugs.python.org/issue4947).

Now one reads the Python wiki page [PrintFails](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails) and goes to try out the following code:

```
$ python -c 'import sys, codecs, locale; print str(sys.stdout.encoding); \
  sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(locale.getpreferredencoding())(sys.stdout);
```

However this too does not work (at least on Mac). Too see why:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'mac-roman'
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

(UTF-8 is what one's terminal understands).

So one changes the above code to:

```
$ python -c 'import sys, codecs, locale; print str(sys.stdout.encoding); \
  sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(sys.stdout.encoding)(sys.stdout);
```

And now unicode strings are properly sent to `sys.stdout` and hence printed properly on the terminal (`sys.stdout` is attached the terminal).

Is this the correct way to write unicode strings in `sys.stdout` or should I be doing something else?

**EDIT**: at times--say, when piping the output to `less`--`sys.stdout.encoding` will be `None`. in this case, the above code will fail.

Comment: s/my/one's/ for consistency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to my why you wouldn't be able to do print; but assuming so, yes, the approach looks right to me.

Comment: One reason I cannot use `print` is to avoid that extra space `print` prints. Look at the use of `sys.stdout` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396820/apt-like-column-output-python-library/1397382#1397382

Comment: You could build up complete lines, and then print them.

Comment: Bravo! Yes, in that case I can use `print`

Comment: adding a comma to the end makes print suppress the newline: print "Some Text",

Comment: adding a comma will not print a newline, but it will print an extra space. try running: python -c "print 2,; print 3,"

Comment: Martin, even using `print` did not help when piping the output to `less`. logging.StreamHandler works fine though.

Comment: If the output is to a pipe, it can't possibly know what encoding to use (as it can't know that less(1) is at the other end of the pipe). So your application will have to determine/decide the encoding for itself.

Comment: In Python 3 you can do `print(stuff, sep='', end='')` to avoid extra spaces. And I suspect the encoding problem isn't present there either.

Answer (score 34):

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

will do the job, but can't set it on python itself ...

what we can do is verify if isn't setting and tell the user to set it before call script with :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (sys.stdout.encoding is None):
        print >> sys.stderr, "please set python env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8, example: export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8, when write to stdout."
        exit(1)
```

Answer (score 10):

Best idea is to check if you are directly connected to a terminal. If you are, use the terminal's encoding. Otherwise, use system preferred encoding.

```
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    default_encoding = sys.stdout.encoding
else:
    default_encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

It's also very important to always allow the user specify whichever encoding she wants. Usually I make it a command-line option (like `-e ENCODING`), and parse it with the `optparse` module.

Another good thing is to **not** overwrite `sys.stdout` with an automatic encoder. Create your encoder and use it, but leave `sys.stdout` alone. You could import 3rd party libraries that write encoded bytestrings directly to `sys.stdout`.

Answer (score 9):

There is an optional environment variable "PYTHONIOENCODING" which may be set to a desired default encoding. It would be one way of grabbing the user-desired encoding in a way consistent with all of Python. It is buried in the Python manual [here](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonioencoding).

Answer (score 7):

This is what I am doing in my application:

`sys.stdout.write(s.encode('utf-8'))`

This is the exact opposite fix for reading UTF-8 names from argv:

```
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    file = file.decode('utf-8')
```

This is very ugly (IMHO) as it force you to work with UTF-8.. which is the norm on Linux/Mac, but not on windows... Works for me anyway :)