# Printing a utf-8 encoded string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I'm using BeautifulSoup to extract some text from an HTML but I just can't figure out how to print it properly to the screen (or to a file for that matter).

Here's how my class containing the text looks like:

```
class Thread(object):
    def __init__(self, title, author, date, content = u""):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.date = date
        self.content = content
        self.replies = []

    def __unicode__(self):
        s = u""

        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            s += u"%s = %s " % (k, v)

        return s

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(unicode(self))

    __str__ = __repr__
```

When trying to print an instance of `Thread` here's what I see on the console:

```
~/python-tests $ python test.py
u'date = 21:01 03/02/11 content =  author = \u05d3"\u05e8 \u05d9\u05d5\u05e0\u05d9 \u05e1\u05d8\u05d0\u05e0\u05e6\'\u05e1\u05e7\u05d5 replies = [] title = \u05de\u05d1\u05e0\u05d4 \u05d4\u05de\u05d1\u05d7\u05df '
```

Whatever I try I cannot get the output I'd like (the above text should be Hebrew). My end goal is to serialize `Thread` to a file (using json or pickle) and be able to read it back.

I'm running this with Python 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue the other day when trying to write to a CSV document with the csv module. PITA. But `encode()` is the way to go.

Comment: i had the same problem , but it was all about not having 'charset=utf8' on my mysql connection !

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To output a Unicode string to a file (or the console) you need to choose a *text encoding*. In Python the default text encoding is ASCII, but to support Hebrew characters you need to use a different encoding, such as UTF-8:

```
s = unicode(your_object).encode('utf8')
f.write(s)
```

Comment: Internally `print x` calls `x.__str__` and in your class you've defined `__str__` to be the same as `__repr__`.

Comment: What should `__str__` do then? If I'm reading the docs properly, it shouldn't return a `unicode` object.

Comment: what is your import statements?

Answer (score 11):

A nice alternative to @mark's answer is to set the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`.

*c.f*. [Writing unicode strings via sys.stdout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473577/writing-unicode-strings-via-sys-stdout-in-python).

(Make sure to set it prior to starting Python not in the script.)

Comment: Yes! But os.putenv('PYTHONIOENCODING', 'UTF-8') in the program didn't work for me?