# Codec python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, codec

I have created some list with special characters. However when I am printing those lists appeared some erros in codec.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#My lists
geometriaAproximada = ['Sim', 'Não'];
regime = ['Permanente', 'Permanente com grande variação', 'Temporário', 
                'Temporário com leito permanente', 'Seco'];
tipomassadagua = ['Oceano', 'Baía', 'Enseada', 'Meandro abandonado', 
                            'Lago/Lagoa', 'Represa/Açude', 'Desconhecida'];
vegetacao_nivel_1 = ['Manguezal', 'Restinga', 'Brejo Litoraneo', 'Mussununga', 
                                'Vegetação com influência fluvial e/ou lacustre', 'Compo Rupestre'
                                'Floresta Estacional', 'Cerrado', 'Caatinga', 'Áreas Antropizadas',
                                'Rios, Lagos, Lagoas, e Corpos d''água'];
vegetacao_nivel_2 = ['Arbustiva/Arbórea', 'Apicum', 'Herbáceo-Arbustivo', 'Arbustiva', 'Herbácea', 
                                'Terras baixas', 'Aluvial' 'de Altitude (Submontana ou Montana)', 'Decidual', 'Semidecidual'
                                'Tipo biogeográfico de Cerrado', 'Tipo biogeográfico de Caatinga'];
vegetacao_nivel_3 = ['Estágio secundário inicial de regeneração', 
                                'Estágio secundário médio de regeneração', 
                                'Estágio primário e/ou secundário avançado de regeneração', 
                                'Mata de Cipó', 'Terras baixas', 'de Altitude (Submontana/Montana)', 'Aluvial', 
                                'Florestado (Cerradão)',  'Arborizado (Stricto sensu)', 'Parque (Campo cerrado)', 'Campo Limpo',
                                'Vereda', 'Floresta de galeria',
                                'Florestada', 'Arborizada', 'Parque', 'Gramínio-lenhosa'];
```

When I printed someone of them:

```
print regime

['Permanente', 'Permanente com grande varia\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o', 'Tempor\xc3\xa1rio', 'Tempor\xc3\xa1rio com leito permanente', 'Seco']
```

What can I do to correct it?

Comment: How about pulling most of the examples out and focus on one short list?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597480/how-to-make-python-3-print-utf8#3603160 or for 2.7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203105/printing-a-utf-8-encoded-string

Comment: `print` can prints only text. If you give something different then it try to convert it to **unambiguous** string - for example if it is list then it adds `[`, `]`, quota marks (for strings) and use hex codes for native characters to show you what exacly encoding was used - so it is not error but intentional action. If you need correct text you have to convert list to string on your own.

Comment: It can be also other problem - `print` automatically try to convert text to encoding used by console. If console doesn't use UTF-8 then sometimes you can see hex code instead of unicode chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode was bolted onto python 2 well after the language was cooked. The `str` object in particular can hold binary encoded data or ascii string data and you just kinda have to know which is which in your program. The `unicode` type was added later and does what you'd expect - it holds wide text characters capable of expressing the unicode code set.

To keep matters confusing, your console and text editors likely support utf-8 natively so a string holding encoded utf-8 octets may look right when you view it. These two strings look the same, but `repr` shows us they are different. The first needs decoding to be a python unicode string

```
>>> s = 'Permanente com grande variação'
>>> u = u'Permanente com grande variação'
>>> print repr(s)
'Permanente com grande varia\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o'
>>> print repr(u)
u'Permanente com grande varia\xe7\xe3o'
>>> s_decode = s.decode('utf-8')
>>> print repr(s_decode)
u'Permanente com grande varia\xe7\xe3o'
```

So, the first part of your problem is solved by writing your strings as unicode to start out with.

```
u'Permanente com grande variação'
```

The second problem is that when you print a list, python will print the `repr` of its members and your strings will still show encoding characters. This doesn't really need fixing - that's just the normal way python prints lists. If you want something tidier, you have to build your own output as in

```
>>> mylist = [u'Permanente com grande variação', u'Vegetação com influência']
>>> print mylist
[u'Permanente com grande varia\xe7\xe3o', u'Vegeta\xe7\xe3o com influ\xeancia']
>>> print u', '.join(mylist)
Permanente com grande variação, Vegetação com influência
```

Finally, python 3 has been out for a very long time and non-english speakers should be especially happy that its done a great job working with international character sets.

Python is dead... long live Python!