# Storing contents of a text file in an array

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file with Hindi text lines(about 5400000 lines) in it. I want to save these lines in a string array in python. I tried this code:

```
    f = open("cleanHindi_Translated.txt" , "r")
    array = []
    for line in f:
        array.append(line)

    print(array)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hindi.py", line 11, in <module>
    for line in f:
  File "C:\Users\Preeti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 124: character maps to <undefined>
PS C:\Users\Preeti\Downloads\Compressed> python hindi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hindi.py", line 11, in <module>
    for line in f:
  File "C:\Users\Preeti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 124: character maps to <undefined>
```

I don't understand on what I did wrong here.

Comment: Haven try something like this before, but I guess should be `.append(line)`.

Comment: I tried to include:  encoding="utf8"  but I am not able to include the read mode - "r" in that case. So I don not think it is a duplicate of that question as the solutions given there have not worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list like this?

Comment: Yes I did try that but ended up getting a similar error.

Comment: Edit question to show your additional attempts. `open` definitely takes an encoding and your error message shows that the encoding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'lines' is the array (list) you are looking for

```
import io
with io.open('my_file.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
```

Comment: I am still getting an error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hindi.py", line 9, in <module>
    lines = f.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\Preeti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 124: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @PraveenIyer I have updated the code.

Comment: This code seems to work but when I tried print(lines)  I am getting outputs with question marks in it instead of hindi text.

Comment: @PraveenIyer see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203105/printing-a-utf-8-encoded-string

Comment: Thank you so much this seems to be working. I'll try and put this all together and get the results i wanted.

Comment: @PraveenIyer I am glad I was able to help. Feel free to vote up.

Comment: Yes I did vote up but since my reputation is less than 15 it is not publicly visible :(