# sys.stdout.encoding is None, how can I fix it without changing the script?

Tags: python, encoding, stdout, piping

If I run a python script using piping, sys.stdout.encoding inside it becomes None and crashes it. How can I get away with it without modifying the script? I cannot modify it for some reason.

Comment: possible duplicates of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473577/writing-unicode-strings-via-sys-stdout-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3 (and several note `PYTHONIOENCODING`)