# lxml encoding error when parsing utf8 xml

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, lxml

I'm trying to iterate through an XML file (UTF-8 encoded, starts with ) with lxml, but get the following error on the character 丂 :

UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character u'\u4e02' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence

Other characters before this are printed out correctly.
The code is:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
tree = etree.parse("filename.xml", parser)
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root:
    print elem[0].text
```

Does the error mean that it didn't parse the file in utf-8 but in shift JIS instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace of the `UnicodeEncodeError` points to the location where the exception occurs.
Unfortunately you didn’t include it but it’s most likely the last line where the unicode text is printed to stdout. I assume that stdout uses `cp932` encoding on your system.

If my assumptions are correct you should consider changing your environment such that stdout uses an encoding that can represent unicode characters (like UTF-8). (see for example [Writing unicode strings via sys.stdout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473577/writing-unicode-strings-via-sys-stdout-in-python)).

Comment: Oh so it was just stdouts encoding, I didn't realize that! I was using it just for testing, so I didn't have a problem after all :D
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation using lxml's objectify. Here's how I was able to fix it.

```
import unicodedata
my_name = root.name.text
if isinstance(my_name, unicode):
    # Decode to string.
    my_name = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', my_name).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for `r = requests.get(...)` that would not work in `objectify.XML(r.text)`