# Python : UnicodeEncodeError when I use grep

Tags: python, grep, python-requests

I am using a simple python script to get reservation results for my CID :
**`simple.py`**:

```
data = {"minorRev":"current minorRev #","cid":"xxx","apiKey":"xxx","customerIpAddress":"  ","creationDateStart":"03/31/2013","}

url = 'http://someservice/services/rs/'                      
req = requests.get(url,params=data)                        
print req                                                                 
print req.text                                                                
print req.status_code
```

Now on the command prompt if I do `python simple.py` it runs perfectly and prints the `req.text` variable

However when I try to do

```
python simple.py | grep pattern
```

I get

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 1314: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii

Comment: read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473577/writing-unicode-strings-via-sys-stdout-in-python).  Basically, when piping the output, `sys.stdout.encoding==None`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`print` **needs** to encode the string before sending to stdout but when the process is in a pipe, the value of `sys.stdout.encoding` is `None`, so `print` receives an `unicode` object and then it tries to encode this object using the `ascii` codec -- if you have non-ASCII characters in this `unicode` object, an exception will be raised.

You can solve this problem encoding all `unicode` objects *before* sending it to the standard output (but you'll need to guess which codec to use). See these examples:

File `wrong.py`:

```
# coding: utf-8

print u'Álvaro'
```

Result:

```
alvaro@ideas:/tmp
$ python wrong.py 
Álvaro
alvaro@ideas:/tmp
$ python wrong.py | grep a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrong.py", line 3, in <module>
    print u'Álvaro'
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

File `right.py`:

```
# coding: utf-8

print u'Álvaro'.encode('utf-8')
# unicode object encoded == `str` in Python 2
```

Result:

```
alvaro@ideas:/tmp
$ python right.py 
Álvaro
alvaro@ideas:/tmp
$ python right.py | grep a
Álvaro
```

Answer (score 7):

If `sys.stdout.isatty()` is false (the output is redirected to a file/pipe) then configure `PYTHONIOENCODING` envvar outside your script.
Always print Unicode, don't hardcode the character encoding of your environment inside your script:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python simple.py | grep pattern
```