# How can I decode MACCYRILLIC using python?

Tags: python-2.7, encoding

I would like to decode MACCYRILLIC code, for example "%EE%F2_%E4%EE%E1%F0%E0_%E4%EE%E1%F0%E0_%ED%E5_%E8%F9%F3%F2". How can I do it using Python2?

`phrase.decode("MACCYRILLIC")` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

[urllib — Open arbitrary resources by URL](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html)

> `urllib.unquote(string)`
>
> Replace `%xx` escapes by their single-character equivalent.
>
> Example: `unquote('/%7Econnolly/')` yields `'/~connolly/'`.

```
==> py -2
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import urllib
>>> MACCYRILLIC = "%EE%F2_%E4%EE%E1%F0%E0_%E4%EE%E1%F0%E0_%ED%E5_%E8%F9%F3%F2"
>>> print urllib.unquote(MACCYRILLIC).decode('cp1251')
от_добра_добра_не_ищут
>>>
```

**Edit**. Another approach (step by step):

```
==> py -2
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> import codecs
>>> MACCYRILLIC = '%EE%F2_%E4%EE%E1%F0%E0_%E4%EE%E1%F0%E0_%ED%E5_%E8%F9%F3%F2'
>>> #print
... x = urllib.unquote(MACCYRILLIC) #.decode('cp1251')
>>> print repr(x)
'\xee\xf2_\xe4\xee\xe1\xf0\xe0_\xe4\xee\xe1\xf0\xe0_\xed\xe5_\xe8\xf9\xf3\xf2'
>>> y = codecs.decode(x, 'cp1251')
>>> print y
от_добра_добра_не_ищут
>>>
```

All above would work on the following requirement:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> print sys.stdout.encoding
utf-8
>>>
```

Unfortunately, the example in http://rextester.com/XAX79891 shows `sys.stdout.encoding` **None** (and I don't know a way of changing it to `utf-8`). Read more in [Lennart Regebro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126214/lennart-regebro)'s answer to [Stdout encoding in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15740694/3439404):

> A better generic solution under Python 2 is to treat `stdout` as what
>   it is: An 8-bit interface. And that means that anything you print to
>   to `stdout` should be 8-bit. You get the error when you are trying to
>   print Unicode data, because print will then try to encode the Unicode
>   data to the encoding of `stdout`, and if it's **None** it will assume
>   `ASCII`, and fail, unless you set `PYTHONIOENCODING`.

Comment: http://rextester.com/XAX79891 it doesn't work. =(    I have the same result:  `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @nik As you can see, the solution works in standard python-2.7 however it would fail in the rextester.com emulator (explained in updated answer).