# How to convert unicode string into normal text in python

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Consider I have a Unicode string (Not the real unicode but the string that looks like unicode). and I want to get it's utf-8 variant. How can I do it in Python?
For example If I have String like:

```
title = "\\u10d8\\u10e1\\u10e0\\u10d0\\u10d4\\u10da\\u10d8 == \\u10d8\\u10d4\\u10e0\\u10e3\\u10e1\\u10d0\\u10da\\u10d8\\u10db\\u10d8"
```

How Can I do it so that I get its utf-8 variant (Georgian symbols):

> ისრაელი == იერუსალიმი

To say it simply I want to Have code like:

```
title = "\\u10d8\\u10e1\\u10e0\\u10d0\\u10d4\\u10da\\u10d8 == \\u10d8\\u10d4\\u10e0\\u10e3\\u10e1\\u10d0\\u10da\\u10d8\\u10db\\u10d8"
utfTitle = title.TurnToUTF()
print(utfTitle)
```

And I want this code to have output:

> ისრაელი == იერუსალიმი

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473577/writing-unicode-strings-via-sys-stdout-in-python

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182635/8179099) can help you...

Comment: @MosheSlavin It doesn't help

Comment: @ozking It doesn't help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [unicode-escape](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) codec to get rid of the doubled-backslashes and use the string effectively.

Assuming that `title` is a `str`, you will need to encode the string first before decoding back to unicode(`str`).

```
>>> t = title.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
>>> t
'ისრაელი == იერუსალიმი'
```

If `title` is a `bytes` instance you can decode directly:

```
>>> t = title.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> t
'ისრაელი == იერუსალიმი'
```

Answer (score 6):

Here, you go. Just use `decode` method and apply `unicode_escape`

For Python 2.x

```
title = "\\u10d8\\u10e1\\u10e0\\u10d0\\u10d4\\u10da\\u10d8 == \\u10d8\\u10d4\\u10e0\\u10e3\\u10e1\\u10d0\\u10da\\u10d8\\u10db\\u10d8"
utfTitle = title.decode('unicode_escape')
print(utfTitle)

#output :ისრაელი == იერუსალიმი
```

For python 3.x

```
title = "\\u10d8\\u10e1\\u10e0\\u10d0\\u10d4\\u10da\\u10d8 == \\u10d8\\u10d4\\u10e0\\u10e3\\u10e1\\u10d0\\u10da\\u10d8\\u10db\\u10d8"
print(title.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**let assume the unicode be str type and convert using decode and unicode-escape 
 method**

```
title="\\u10d8\\u10e1\\u10e0\\u10d0\\u10d4\\u10da\\u10d8 == \\u10d8\\u10d4\\u10e0\\u10e3\\u10e1\\u10d0\\u10da\\u10d8\\u10db\\u10d8"

res1 = title.encode('utf-8')

res2 = res1.decode('unicode-escape')

print(res2)
```

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character '\u10d8' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence