# I can't convert a unicode into a plain string

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm get stuck triyng to transform only one word from unicode into a plain string. I look for answers but no one help me to solve this simple problem.

I'v already tried the following links:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch03s18.html

[Convert a Unicode string to a string in Python (containing extra symbols)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207457/convert-a-unicode-string-to-a-string-in-python-containing-extra-symbols)

[How to convert unicode string into normal text in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006240/how-to-convert-unicode-string-into-normal-text-in-python/48006486)

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.mpgo.mp.br/coliseu/concursos/inscricoes_abertas')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'grid'})

text = table.get_text()
text_str = text[0:7]
text_str = text_str.encode('utf-8')

test_str = 'Nenhum'
test_str = test_str.encode('utf-8')

if text_str == test_str:
    print('Ok they are equal')
else:
    print(id(text_str))
    print(id(test_str))
    print(type(test_str))
    print(type(test_str))
    print(test_str)
    print(test_str)```

My spected result is: text_str being equal test_str
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.  You have a typo in your debug output.  The last 4 values are all te**s**t_str instead of some te**x**t_str.

Then you would have noticed that your read in variable contains:

```
'\nNenhum'
```

So if you either change your slice to: text_str = text[**1**:7] or if you set your test string accordingly:

```
test_str = '\nNenhum'
```

It works.  Happy hacking...

Comment: HeyMan, you just saved my life. On the next time I'll pay more attetion into input of my code.