# lisp-style style `let` syntax in Python list-comprehensions

Tags: refactoring, lisp, python

Consider the following code:

```
>>> colprint([
        (name, versions[name][0].summary or '')
        for name in sorted(versions.keys())
    ])
```

What this code does is to print the elements of the dictionary `versions` in ascending order of its `keys`, but since the `value` is another sorted list, only the summary of its *first* element (the 'max') is printed.

Since I am familiar with `let` from lisp, I rewrote the above as:

```
>>> colprint([
        (name, package.summary or '')
        for name in sorted(versions.keys())
        for package in [versions[name][0]]
    )]
```

Do you think this violates [being Pythonic](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)? Can it be improved?

Note: For the curious, `colprint` is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396820/apt-like-column-output-python-library/1397382#1397382).

Comment: Heh.  Trying to be lispy is _always_ unpythonic.  Python tries not to be lispy as hard as it can.

Comment: It's tough to speak Parsel with a lisp ;[.

Comment: python doesn't try to not be like lisp. GvR Himself has said that PYthon and Lisp are very similar, and that the differences are more superficial. I come from a scheme back ground myself, but I have been using python almost exclusively for three years now, and I like the second way more than the first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not exploit tuples?

```
colprint([(name, version[0].summary or '')
      for (name, version) in sorted(versions.iteritems())])
```

or, even

```
colprint(sorted([(name, version[0].summary or '')
             for (name, version) in versions.iteritems()]))
```

Also, you may consider (in my first example) removing the `[]`s, because that way you get a generator instead of a list (which may or may not be useful, since I'm guessing this'll print the whole array, so you won't be saving any evaluations).

Comment: I was about to suggest the same

Comment: Looks better; except I'd use `items()` instead of `iteritems()` as that is deprecated in Py3k (and `colprint` accepts a flattened list anyway)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use the "tricky for clause" (or "let-equivalent") in most cases, but I would if it's the natural way to avoid repetition, especially costly repetition.  E.g.

```
xs = [(y, y*1.2, y-3.4) for z in zs for y in [somefun(z)] ]
```

looks much better to me than calling `somefun` three times!-)  So, it's worth keeping in mind, even if probably not worth using where it does not remove repetition.

Answer (score 4):

So you're using "for x in [y]" as a substitute for "let x y".

Trying to emulate language's syntax in another language is never a good idea. I think that the original version is much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

As Tordek says, you can use `items()` or `iteritems()` in this case to avoid the issue:

```
colprint(sorted((name, packages[0].summary or '')
                for (name, packages) in versions.items()))
```

Moving the sorting outside is a nice touch.

[Note that the use of `items()` changed the sorting order slightly - it used to be by name with ties resolved by original order (Python sort is stable), now it's by name with ties resolved by summary.  Since the original order of a dict is random, the new behaviour is probably better.]

But for other uses (such as Alex Martelli's example), a "let"-alike might still be useful.
I've also once discovered the `for var in [value]` trick, but I now find it ugly.
A cleaner alternative might be a "pipeline" of comprehensions / generators, using the "decorate/undecorate" trick to pass the added value in a tuple:

```
# You could write this with keys() or items() - 
# I'm just trying to examplify the pipeline technique.
names_packages = ((name, versions[name][0]) 
                  for name in versions.keys())

names_summaries = ((name, package.summary or '')
                   for (name, package) in names_packages)

colprint(sorted(names_summaries))
```

Or applied to Alex's example:

```
ys = (somefun(z) for z in zs)
xs = [(y, y*1.2, y-3.4) for y in ys]
```

(in which you don't even need the original `z` values, so the intermediate values don't have to be tuples.)

See http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/ for more powerful examples of the "pipeline" technique...

Answer (score 0):

You can move the sorting to the end to avoid some intermediate lists.

This looks a bit nicer i guess:

```
colprint(sorted(
        (name, version[0].summary or '')
        for (name,version) in versions.iteritems())
    ))
```

Python3 can do even better:

```
colprint(sorted(
        (name, first_version.summary or '')
        for (name,(first_version,*_)) in versions.items())
    ))
```