# python - raw_input and thread

Tags: python, linux

I have a thread that verifies results of my database and raw_input to input more data. The problem is that the thread is printed on the raw_input. Something like that.

```
input> DATAOFTHREAD
```

but I want to print the result something like that

```
DATAOFTHREAD
input>
```

...

```
def handler(de_user,idChat):
    db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','user','passwd','database')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    oldata = 0
    write = sys.stdout.write
    while True:
        db.commit()
        cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM mensajes WHERE De_user='%s' AND idChat='%s' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1"%(de_user,idChat))
        traer_id = cursor.fetchall()
        if traer_id:
            for j in traer_id:
                data = j[0]
        if oldata != 0:
            if oldata != data:
                cursor.execute("SELECT Mensaje FROM mensajes WHERE De_user='%s' AND id>'%d'"%(de_user,oldata))
                traer_mensajes = cursor.fetchall()
                if traer_mensajes:
                    for i in traer_mensajes:
                        Mensaje = i[0]
                        Mensaje = base64.decodestring(Mensaje)
                        write(de_user+' > '+Mensaje)
                        write('\n')
                    oldata = data
        else:
            oldata = data

t = Thread(target=handler, args=(de_user, idChat))
t.daemon = True
t.start()
while True:
    contestar = raw_input('> ')
    print "\033[A                                        \033[A"
    #Validations
```

**SOLVED:**
[Reading input from raw_input() without having the prompt overwritten by other threads in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082387/reading-input-from-raw-input-without-having-the-prompt-overwritten-by-other-th)

thanks to those who helped me

Comment: ok, It is a small part

Comment: yes yuvi, but the result is displayed below the raw_input

Comment: Yeah I saw, that was why I deleted the comment. I'm thinking the thread just finishes after the `raw_input`. Why are you... not using print? Why use a thread at all if you need this synchronous?

Comment: I am creating a chat, the thread is to for show new messages that come to me. The raw_input is to send messages to another user.