# Killing stdout in python breaks get_line_buffer()

Tags: python, multithreading, stdout, raw-input

So I'm using some libraries that (unfortunately and much to my chagrin) print to stdout for certain debug info. Okay, no problem, I just disabled it with:

```
import sys,os
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull,'wb')
```

I've recently added code for getting user input and printing output in the terminal, which of course needs stdout. But again, no problem, instead of `print` I can just do:

```
sys.__stdout__.write('text\n')
```

Finally, since I'm doing `raw_input` in a separate thread and the program's output can interrupt the user typing, I wanted to re-echo the test as described [in the first part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653306/2258915) to make it more or less seamless using `readline.get_line_buffer()`. For example, if the user entered `foobar`:

```
> foobar
```

And then another thread says `Interrupting text!` it should look like:

```
Interrupting text!
> foobar
```

But instead I observe:

```
Interrupting text!
>
```

It turns out that `readline.get_line_buffer()` is always blank, and the code fails to re-echo what the user had typed. If I remove the `sys.stdout` override, everything works as expected (except now the debug output from libraries isn't blocked).

I'm using Python 2.7 on Linux if that matters. Perhaps what I want to do is impossible, but I'd really like to know why this is happening. In my mind, doing things with `stdout` shouldn't affect the `stdin` line buffer, but I'm admittedly not familiar with the underlying libraries or implementation.

A minimum working example is below. Just type something and wait for the interrupting text. The prompt `"> "` will be re-echoed, but the text you entered won't be. Simply comment out the second line to see it work correctly. When the thread prints, it logs the line buffer to `stdin.log`.

```
import time,readline,thread,sys,os
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull,'wb')  # comment this line!

def noisy_thread():
  while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    line = readline.get_line_buffer()
    with open('stdin.log','a') as f:
      f.write(time.asctime()+' | "'+line+'"\n')
    sys.__stdout__.write('\r'+' '*(len(line)+2)+'\r')
    sys.__stdout__.write('Interrupting text!\n')
    sys.__stdout__.write('> ' + line)
    sys.__stdout__.flush()

thread.start_new_thread(noisy_thread, ())
while True:
    sys.__stdout__.write('> ')
    s = raw_input()
```

I've also tried `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` right before the `get_line_buffer()` call, but that doesn't work either. Any help or explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd send a pull request to those libraries to use `logging` instead, because printing to stdout *or* stderr from library code is ridiculous. Or at least file a bug report. And maybe name and shame :P

Comment: I also just wrote a quick wrapper class and it appears that anything that replaces `stdout` breaks the readline behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I did do that, but in the meantime I'd still really like to know _why_ this is happening :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it's a super weird problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the `raw_input()` that stops working when you redirect the stdout.
If you try `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` just before the `raw_input()` it works again. 
Both `stdin` and `stdout` need to be connected to the terminal in order for `raw_input` to work.

Comment: Now that you've said it that makes so much sense; just couldn't work it out for myself. Thanks!