# python Pretty printing a list in a tabular format

Tags: python, printing

I am referring to a post here [Pretty printing a list in a tabular format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200288/pretty-printing-a-list-in-a-tabular-format)

```
mylist = [ ( (12, 47, 4, 574862, 58, 7856), 'AGGREGATE_VALUE1'),
           ( (2, 75, 757, 8233, 838, 47775272785), 'AGGREG2'),
           ( (4144, 78, 78965, 778, 78578, 2), 'AGGREGATE_VALUE3')]

header = ('Price1','Price2','reference','XYD','code','resp','AGGREG values')

longg = dict(zip((0,1,2,3,4,5,6),(len(str(x)) for x in header)))

for tu,x in mylist:
    longg.update(( i, max(longg[i],len(str(el))) ) for i,el in enumerate(tu))
    longg[6] = max(longg[6],len(str(x)))
fofo = ' | '.join('%%-%ss' % longg[i] for i in xrange(0,7))

print '\n'.join((fofo % header,
                 '-|-'.join( longg[i]*'-' for i in xrange(7)),
                 '\n'.join(fofo % (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) for (a,b,c,d,e,f),g in mylist)))
```

I want to replace `'\n'.join(fofo % (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) for (a,b,c,d,e,f),g in mylist)))` with something dynamic.
For example `range1 = ', '.join(map(chr, range(97, 97+7)))` which gives me a,b,c,d,e,f,g

so the line will look `'\n'.join(fofo % (range1) for (a,b,c,d,e,f),g in mylist)))`

but gives me:

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (a,b,c,d,e,f),g  are two parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that range1 is a string while you expect to have variables. You perhaps may use something like [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)?

So you can do:

```
    '\n'.join(fofo % eval(range1) for (a,b,c,d,e,f),g in mylist)
```

Or to avoid refering to several vars:

```
    '\n'.join(fofo % (tuple(x[0])+(x[1],)) for x in mylist)
```

Each element of `mylist` is made by a tuple containing a tuple and a string like `((a,b..), "string")`.
So if you consider x containing such data, `tuple(x[0])` designate the first tuple while `(x[1],)` make a tuple with single element that is the string. Finally `tuple(x[0])+(x[1],)` will create only one tuple with all elements like:

```
    x = ((0, 1, 2), "a")
    tuple(x[0])+(x[1],)  #is equivalent to (0, 1, 2, "a")
```

This will work with `((0, 1, 2, 3, 4), "a")`, or any number of element in the inside tuple.

Comment: eval worked. How do I pass the same in the for loop. \n'.join(fofo % eval(range1) for (range2),g in mylist) ??

Comment: range1 = ', '.join(map(chr, range(97, 97+7)))
range2 = ', '.join(map(chr, range(98, 97+7)))

'\n'.join(fofo % (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) for a,(b,c,d,e,f,g) in myList)))  — works
'\n'.join(fofo % (eval(range1)) for a,(range2) in myList))) — does not work - error NameError: name 'b' is not defined
'\n'.join(fofo % (eval(range1)) for a,(eval(range2)) in myList))) - does not work - error SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: That cannot work as the vars you want to evaluate don't exist. It is not the same case than in range1

Comment: how can I do this? I am trying to dynamically trying to set the range so I can use as long as I know the count of header elements and avoid hard coding it. Thanks Thomas

Comment: I can't see an other way than something like: '\n'.join(fofo % (tuple(x[0])+(x[1],)) for x in mylist)

Comment: \n'.join(fofo % (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) for a,(b,c,d,e,f,g) in myList)))


'\n'.join(fofo % (eval(range1)) for a,(b,c,d,e,f,g) in myList)))

above two works

How can I replace (b,c,d,e,f,g) based on some count

Comment: see just before my last answer

Comment: '\n'.join(fofo % (tuple(x[0])+(x[1],)) for x in mylist)

Comment: I need it to be dynamic. Your last answer I did not understand. The tuple need to be dynamically build based on some count? The count is number of elements in the header it needs to print. Thanks Thomas